# Not able to perform DML on case comment object

Tags: apex

I'm tring to write a apex simple method which could save a case comment recod. But when I'm trying to save the class i'm getting some compile error. Following is the method-

```
 @AuraEnabled

 public static void saveComment(string caseId, string caseCommentBody, string caseCommentId)

    {
        caseComment cc = new caseComment();
        if(!String.isBlank(caseCommentId))
        {
            cc.id = caseCommentId;        
        }
        cc.CommentBody = caseCommentBody;
        cc.ParentId = caseId;
        upsert cc;            
    }
```

This the screen shot of the error I'm getting -
[image]

Can any one please tell reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error logs you're showing, it looks like you've named your class `CaseComment`. This shadows the built-in sObject type `CaseComment` (note that Apex is case-insensitive, so the fact that you are writing it `caseComment` doesn't matter). When Apex sees

```
caseComment cc = new caseComment();
```

it reads that as "make a new instance of *this class*, which is called `CaseComment`". Then, your class has no property `Id`, `CommentBody`, or `ParentId`, and cannot have DML performed on it - it's not an sObject.

Simple fix: change your class's name.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's absolutely got out of my notice.

Answer (score 0):

While @DavidReed has identified the cause, I would offer an alternative solution just so you are aware of it:

```
Schema.CaseComment record = new Schema.CaseComment();
```

Comment: I still wouldn't recommend this approach. It can have amusing, production-breaking side effects later if you're not careful.

Comment: Yeah shadowing at the top level is ill advised. But inner classes sometimes are way more convenient/appropriate as a shadow. It's pretty vital to at least know you can use the explicit Schema reference.